# How should I combine A* with steering?

Tags: path-finding, steering-behaviors

I want to combine A* pathfinding with evasion, pursuit, and fleeing.  For example, if I tell an agent to move to a position and avoid enemy agents on the way, it will create an A* path towards that point, and try to move along the path while also trying to avoid enemy agents.

There are plenty of tutorials online about A* and plenty of tutorials about steering behaviors, but I can't find anything that talks about using the two in unison.

Is the following the correct way to implement this?

1. Calculate the agent's destination vector as a vector from the agent's current position to the A* path's next waypoint.
2. Calculate the agent's steering vector using standard steering calculations.  For example, when evading an enemy agent, the steering vector will point directly away from the enemy agent.  If multiple agents are being evaded, the steering vector will be a sum of those two evasion vectors.
3. Calculate the agent's movement vector as the sum of the vectors from step 1 and step 2.  Move the agent according to this vector.
4. Repeat steps 1-3 each frame.
5. Periodically calculate a new A* path for the agent since best the path to destination may change as the agent moves around while evading enemy agents.

Assuming the above is correct, I have a follow-up question.  I tried implementing the above behavior and a problem I'm running into is when an agent is trying to avoid an enemy who is directly in between him and the destination.  In this case, the steering (evasion) vector points in the opposite direction as the destination vector.  Adding those two vectors together results in a zero vector, so the agent doesn't move.  How should I handle this?  Should I force to the agent to move perpendicularly to the enemy in this situation to break out of this cycle?

Comment: What if instead of using your local avoidance-based evasion vector, you changed your A* heuristic so that it had a higher cost for moves that went closer to enemies?

Comment: @Foxwarrior Thanks for the comment; I think that's a good idea.  Unfortunately I don't think I'll be able to do that because the A* library that I'm using only maintains a single graph for the entire scene, and I have multiple agents which may or may not be evading the same enemy agent.  The enemy team will use this behavior too, so they couldn't use the same graph(s) as the player's team.